# Large inline SVG doesn't get fully drawn

Tags: html, svg

- I'm having a **SVG file** that's around 6300 lines long. Opening this file as `.svg` in Chrome works just fine. But as soon as I use it inline in an **HTML file** via the `<object>` tag only half the elements are drawn.
- With Chrome's `"analyze element"` option I see, that the source for the embedded SVG is cut off.
- I also tried Firefox, but here the SVG is as empty as before, with the only difference, that the missing elements are drawn underneath in strange **positions**.
- If I open the SVG as external data via `<object data="">` it works fine, but that is not a viable option, since my scripts are not properly working that way.

Because the SVG contains confidential data I can't link it here. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Any error in the browser console? Can you reproduce the issue with smaller files? Without a sample svg it will be hard to guess the problem.

Comment: `6300 lines long`... Uhlalaa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is not a parsing problem with the file that is only happening when it is inlined?  SVG renderers will generally stop rendering when they encounter the problem.

I would start by trying to locate the element it stops at. Then look for any oddities.

Comment: Thank you, found the problem.

Visio (with which I'm generating the SVGs) has inserted `foreignData` that causes the SVG to stop rendering.

If I delete those lines it continues until the next `foreignData`